# Creating multiple Word paragraphs with Document.Paragraphs.Add()

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm using a macro in Excel to add information to a Word document. I'm trying to add 10 lines to an existing Word document like this:

```
Sub AddParagraphs()

    'Open Word
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Open
    Dim doc As Word.document
    Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\temp\document.docx")

    'Add 10 paragraphs
    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To 10

        Dim paragraph As Word.paragraph
        Set paragraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add()

        paragraph.Range.style = wdStyleHeading2
        paragraph.Range.text = "Paragraph " & CStr(idx)

    Next

    doc.Save

    doc.Close
    wordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

I have an empty Word document at C:\temp\document.docs but after running the code there is only one line with the text "Paragraph 10". I was expecting 10 lines.

As far as I can tell the Paragraphs.Add() with no arguments should create a new paragraph. Perhaps I'm mistaken to believe that a new paragraph produces a new line? Is there another way to add 10 lines in a loop where each can have a specific (not the same) style?

Comment: Instead of using `doc.Paragraphs.Add` try using `doc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter`. That should add a paragraph at the end of the document, which is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "paragraph" that you are adding does not have a paragraph mark at the end.

Change that line to

```
paragraph.Range.Text = "Paragraph " & CStr(idx) & vbCr
```

and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `vbLf` over `vbCrLf`? Just curious - I've always used `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing missing was the vbLf character. If that is required, was the paragraphs invalid or something when it was missing? Considering only the text for the last one was displayed. The text Paragraph 1.... 9 was nowhere to be found.

Comment: @johanrex They were being placed, but because you never move down a line you were overriding them.

Comment: @dwirony Were they though? I did Ctrl+A on the document and pasted into notepad in order to get all the text. But only the last "Paragraph 10" showed up. Perhaps you're right and Word does some magic in order to not show invisible paragraphs.

Comment: @johanrex They were :). If you step through your code, you can see them being placed as well.

Comment: I tried vbCrLf (on a Mac actually) and it inserted two paragraph marks. So... trial and error :)

Comment: @dwirony Ah, yes. The code absolutely adds the paragraphs. It's just that only the last one is visible in the Word document. And the Ctrl+A in Word only selects the text for the last one for some reason. That's a little weird but I'm happy that the problem is solved.

Comment: @johanrex The correct way to specify a paragraph character in Word is vbCr. If you use anything else you can get very strange results because Word doesn't always interpret other characters correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what's happening in the original code is that you're always *replacing* the content when you use

```
Doc.Paragraphs.Add
```

So there's only ever the one paragraph. There are various ways to get around this. One is to use `InsertAfter`, as has been mentioned in comments. (Note that if you're going to use this, the correct way to specify a new paragraph as part of a string is `vbCr` or Chr(13). Word can very easily misinterpret anything else!)

My personal preference is to work with a `Range` object that can be manipulated independently of the entire document. For example, it can be done like this:

```
Sub AddParagraphs()

    'Open Word
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Open
    Dim doc As Word.document
    Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\temp\document.docx")
    Dim rng as Word.Range
    Set rng = doc.Content

    'Add 10 paragraphs
    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To 10

        Dim paragraph As Word.paragraph
        'So that the next thing inserted follows instead of replaces
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd           
        Set paragraph = rng.Paragraphs.Add

        paragraph.Range.style = wdStyleHeading2
        paragraph.Range.text = "Paragraph " & CStr(idx)
     Next

    doc.Save

    doc.Close
    wordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: `rngCollapse wdCollapseEnd` Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here but I don't get what this does. It's not a function/method call and it's not a declaration or assignment. What is it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, a typo: `rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Adding `doc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter` fixed my problems. The following code should work for you:

```
Sub AddParagraphs()

    'Open Word
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Open
    Dim doc As Word.document
    Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\temp\document.docx")

    'Add 10 paragraphs
    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To 10

        Dim paragraph As Word.paragraph
        Set paragraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add()

        paragraph.Range.style = wdStyleHeading2
        paragraph.Range.text = "Paragraph " 

        doc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    Next

    doc.Save

    doc.Close
    wordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Paragraphs.Add` method appends a new paragraph consisting of the paragraph mark only at the end of the document. Oddly enough, the return value is not the now last paragraph but the penultimate paragraph. You get a reference to the new last paragraph by the `Next` method of the paragraph object. You can then set the style and insert text with the `paragraph.Range.InsertBefore` method.

The critical part of your code must be like this

```
'Add 10 paragraphs
 Dim idx As Integer
 Dim paragraph As word.paragraph
 For idx = 1 To 10
   Set paragraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add.Next
   paragraph.Range.style = word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2
   paragraph.Range.InsertBefore "Paragraph " & CStr(idx)
 Next
```