# How to bold only a portion of Word paragraph in Visual Studio (VB)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to export a Word document from a Visual Basic program. Different parts of the document will need different formatting.

I have several paragraphs, and I need to bold only portions of each of those paragraphs. I am trying to set the range within each paragraph that needs to be bolded, but no matter what I do, it only seems to want to to bold the *entire* paragraph.

I want to do something like this:

```
Dim Para1 As Word.Paragraph
Para1 = WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
Para1.Range.Start = 1
Para1.Range.End = 14
Para1.Range.Font.Bold = True
Para1.Range.Text = "Job number is: " + myJobID
```

... so that it bolds from the 'J' to the ':' (in Para1.Range.Text) but does not bold the myJobID (which is a variable I'm getting from the user). However, no matter what I do, it bolds the entire paragraph, including the myJobID.

I've also tried creating a Range variable that sets a range based on the entire document, but the problem with that is, the lengths of several variables I'm outputting on the Word document are going to be varying sizes, and thus there's no way to know where the start of the next section I want to bold will start at. So basically, I *have* to work within the Paragraph object rather than iterating through all of the characters in the entire document.

Hope that made sense. Any ideas?

Comment: You set the bold property on an empty paragraph, then added the text. Do it the other way around.e.g add the paragraph, add the text, set the sub range then finally apply formatting to the sub range.

Answer (score 2):

In order to format individual text runs it's necessary to break the text down into individual runs when inserting. Also, it's best to work with an independent `Range` object. Between formatting commands the `Range` needs to be "collapsed" - think of it like pressing the right (or left) arrow of a selection to make it a blinking cursor. Something along these lines

```
Dim Para1 As Word.Paragraph
Dim rng as Word.Range
Para1 = WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
rng = Para1.Range
rng.Text = "Job number is: "
rng.Font.Bold = True
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
rng.Text = myJobID
rng.Font.Bold = False
rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```

If it's really necessary to insert the full text in one go, then Find/Replace to locate the text that should be formatted differently is one way to format after-the-fact, although less efficient.

Another possibility is to use string manipulation functions, such as `Instr` (or `Contains`), `Left`, `Mid` etc. to determine where in a longer string the substring is located. Then `Range.Start` and `Range.End` can work with those values. But generally it's better to *not* rely on the `start` and `end` values since Word can insert non-visible characters that can throw this numbering off.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a typo elsewhere.I think this is working, but I have to play around with some other stuff.

Comment: Copied from comment by @JohnA posted to wrong Answer: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, when I try this, nothing shows up at all - the entire line does not even print. I think you misplaced some quotation marks because if I try your code literally, it prints out three entire lines of code literally on the Word doc (basically, lines 5-8 on your code). So I put a quotation mark after "Job ID is ". Also, you needed parentheses surrounding Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @JohnA - I was typing on a mobile device, off the top of my head... Sorry for the confusion! I've made the changes in the code in the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create another `Range` object that only covers the characters that you want to bold.

The code below is not tested (don't have full VS set up on this machine), but should give you an idea:

```
Dim para1 As Word.Paragraph
Dim textToBeBolded As Word.Range

para1 = WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add 'ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Add in VBA
para1.Range.Text = "Job number is: " + myJobID
para1.Range.SetRange 1, 14
textToBeBolded = para1.Range
textToBeBolded.SetRange 1, 14
textToBeBolded.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: If I do that it throws an error message. I can't do:   textToBeBolded = Para1.Range(1,14)

Comment: And of course I declared it in a new Range: Dim textToBeBolded As Word.Range

Comment: I don't have SetRange either. Is there another library I should be referencing besides the Word object library?

Comment: What error message? As noted, I could not test the code itself - but the concept of creating a separate sub-range and then applying the font modifiers to that sub-range is the important concept here.

Comment: `SetRange` is a method called from a `Range` object : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.setrange

Comment: In textToBeBolded = Para1.Range(1,14), it tells me it can't pass more than 1 parameter. It's a read-only property.

Comment: I'm also trying: Dim boldedtext As Word.Range
          boldedtext.SetRange(1, 14) but it throws an error

Comment: wait a few minutes - I am testing something in VBA.

Comment: Dim textToBeBolded As Word.Range = Para0.Range ... and then .... textToBeBolded.SetRange(1, 14) .... doesn't bold anything at all

Comment: @JohnA: I have edited the post. I have tested this in VBA, but did the mental conversion to VB.Net for the post. The code worked as you wanted in VBA - bolded to the colon (except in my code it only added one paragraph and didn't continue to add paragraphs each time I ran it?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121575/creating-multiple-word-paragraphs-with-document-paragraphs-add refers to the problem I noted at the end of my last comment. Not directly an answer to your question, but probably worth noting for the rest of your code.